# How to config a simple Go project

Tags: go, configuration, gopath

I'm trying to follow the Writing an intepreter in Go book, by Thorsten Ball, and in the first chapter he establish this simple scheme

```
file /Users/myuser/projects/monkey/token/token.go
file /Users/myuser/projects/monkey/lexer/lexer.go
file /Users/myuser/projects/monkey/lexer/lexer_test.go
```

In lexer/lexer.go and lexer/lexer_test.g the files start as

```
package lexer
```

And in lexer_test.go the imports are

```
import (
    "testing"
    "monkey/token"
)
```

Then he says that for running the test, I have to run (from /Users/myuser/projects/monkey directory):

```
go test lexer/lexer_test.go
```

But when I do this, I receive the error:

```
lexer/lexer_test.go:6:2: cannot find package "monkey/token" in any of:
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/monkey/token (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/myuser/golang/src/monkey/token (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]
FAIL
```

I've been trying to understand how to configure the packages in go, but I found a lot of very complicated documentation about GOPATH, GOROOT and go.mod. I've been trying all this approach without get rid of the issue.

Can someone help me please? I'm sure is a simple fix but I cannot figure it out :(

Comment: The go tool works with packages, don’t try to build and test individual files.

Comment: Follow the steps in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: I'm following the instructions of the book. And the book is clear: go test lexer/lexer_test.go

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the compiler couldn't find the package locally.

Are you sure you have installed the package?

You may need to do `go get [packagename]`

For e.g., `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports`

Comment: the package is the one I'm writing (following the instructions on the book). The problem is that go cannot find him, that is what I haven't able to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question correctly. Is 'token' a package in the 'monkey' project? If so, delete go.mod and re-initialize with `go mod init monkey`.

Answer (score 0):

For Golang, It will find package first from go root then go path then import from outside. So basically, you should have that package `monkey/token` in your go root or go path.
I don't think it is about goimport because monkey/token didn't seem to be official lib that can be import.
When I first try Golang I have the same problem. I solve by create that package in go path (your working dir) or create that package from your book.